# CSS3 MultiColumn element with multiple rows

Tags: css, multiple-columns

If you have a lot of text and use a css multicolumn element, the columns tend to get longer than the screen which is really annoying to read. In the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) there is some talk of rows but I'm not sure how to make use of that. It is also said that in case of paged media the overflowing columns can be displayed on the next page. However, I'm not sure how I would use this for a div in the browser.

What I'm interested in is to have a fixed height and width for the columns. Then, as many as possible should be displayed per row.

Ok let me add some code:

suppose I have a simple div with

```
div {
    -webkit-column-width: 400px;
    -moz-column-width: 400px;
    column-width: 400px;
    width: 820px;
}
```

Now if there is a lot of text such as in this example http://jsfiddle.net/5jqwd/6/ this is not nice to read anymore. It would be far better readable if there was some kind of page like structure as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/5jqwd/4/. Of course I don't want to manually tell the browser where each page starts or ends.

Comment: Most of us are programmers here, not psychics. So we can't help you much unless you show some code and point where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Ok I added some code.

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/5jqwd/7/)?

Comment: That doesn't even have columns anymore